# Server is too slow eventhough hardware status seems normal?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, dell-poweredge, performance-monitoring, perfomance

I couldn't figure out what's going with our win2k8 server, everything working except its slow to respond and would take much longer to open any window or options than normal. All the status including CPU, memory, network were normal in task manager and there is no activity running on this machine.

I ran resource manager, it was stable there with an available memory of more than 75 percent, the processor utilising around 7 % and disk I/0 is less than normal?

Comment: Is the server hardware or virtual?

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy , its a physical machine, there is no activity running here ,this is a failover server.

Comment: Check SMART attributes of all your disks. If you will found nonzero counter `Current pending sectors` than you will have bad disk. Such disk has very slowly performance.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy  , How to check for SMART  attributes

Comment: You can download `smartmontools` from  https://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/files/smartmontools/6.5/. Documentation is https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/TocDoc